# Automate desktop screen brightness according to daytime on external monitor

Tags: display, brightness

I am using a regular external monitor with a PC and would like to be able to adjust the brightness of the monitor according to daytime automatically.

So, in the morning it should start a bit darker and gradually get brighter towards midday. And in the evening it should slowly get a bit darker towards night.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) now and am very happy with it :)

Answer (score 1):

I have written a program which does exactly this:

It changes monitor brightness (not colour temperature) based on the time of sunset and sunrise:

It is available here: https://github.com/jacob-pro/solar-screen-brightness

It works for both external displays (DDC/CI) and laptop screens.

Comment: Cool! I'm currently also using f.lux and for the automatic brightness I've found the Benq EW3270U to do just that, but thanks anyway. Actually, I'm currently looking for a way to do this with my Sony Android TV - there is no setting or app (yet) for that one I'm afraid...

Answer (score 0):

I found this one called iris, but don't know if it works with multiple screens and the worst part that it's not free. Below is a 7 day trial.
https://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/Iris-Pro.shtml#download